# Issue in running gulp.series()

Tags: gulp, gulp-task

I have task to minify the JS files when it's in production

```
function scriptsToMinify() {
 if(require('yargs').argv.production)
 {
  return gulp.src(src.JSFile)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(ngAnnotate(
    {
      remove: true,
      add: true,
      single_quotes: true
    }))
  .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
 }
}
```

When i run locally its not running the depend tasks

```
gulp.task('inject-scripts', gulp.series(scriptsToMinify, function() {

  var thridPartyScripts = gulp.src(src.thirdPartyJS, { read: false })      
  var scripts = gulp.src([src.app_js, src.directiveJS], { read: false })

  return gulp.src('views/index.html')
.pipe(inject(series(thridPartyScripts, scripts))) // Inject files in an order to run the application without any dependency error.
.pipe(cachebust({ // Add the timestamp to the injected files to avoid cache issue
  type: 'timestamp'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('views'));
});
```

The above task is throwing me below error.

```
 The following tasks did not complete: default, inject-scripts, scriptsToMinify
 Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Comment: So you have problem when not running for production?

Comment: Yes when its not production, its throwing the error. This same file we are using for product and local development. In GUlp 3 its taking empty depend task, but in new gulp 4 its not allowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scriptsToMinify task into

```
function scriptsToMinify(done) {
 if(require('yargs').argv.production)
 {
  return gulp.src(src.JSFile)
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(ngAnnotate(
    {
      remove: true,
      add: true,
      single_quotes: true
    }))
  .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
 }
else{
  done();
}
}
```

You have to return signal when task is finished, so you have to pass callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I didn't aware that we can return like this. Your code works!!!